# JMeter recording .Net application gets wrong response

Tags: .net, performance, jmeter, load-testing

During the recording through the **Jmeter** tool we are getting the response

```
<result><success>true</success><id>0</id>Id>0</placementDetailId></result>
```

While in case of success we are getting some ids like `45763` in place of `0` while other tools like **badboy** or **Blazemeter** are able to record this request successfully.

Actually, I am using the *Jmeter 3.2* for recording this `.net` application.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify / detail your question showing in View Results Tree what you get, otherwise I am afraid nobody can help you.

Comment: We are getting this error at the time of recording through the Jmeter tool not any other tool like badboy and Blazemter

Comment: I have attached the Jmeter Error image in the above link (Jmeter Error Image Link)

Comment: What is your actual question? Don't forget to add a clear question to your question body, preferable indicated by a question mark at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks Zabuza to guide me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching in [Http/s Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) the implementation from default to Java and record again.

[image: Switching HTTP Implementation to Java]

Comment: Thanks a lot UBIK LOAD PACK team and big thanks to resolve my issue 